# Positioning the mouse pointer on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, pageload

Is it possible using javascript to automatically position the mouse pointer upon page load, so that it is hovering over a specified "div" when the page loads, regardless of where the user had their mouse pointer positioned prior to page load?

I've seen a few posts upon searching in relation to automatically positioning mouse cursers in text fields on page load, but not positioning the mouse pointer on page load.

Comment: I dont think we can do that automatically

Comment: If you are using script trigger the hover functionality then you can manually trigger the mouse events... but actually positioning the mouse seems to be impossible

Comment: Its OS stuff, and it makes sens to me, that this cant be done...

Comment: It would be a security risk for the browser to expose that kind of control to websites. Not to mention just plain bad UX. The user does not want you messing with their cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there's no way to position the mouse pointer! Why do you want to force the use behaviour anyway? You could focus on input fields onLoad or use your screen design to guide the user to the required location if this is helpful for you.